# What is the diagram for the limit that is the Cartesian product?

Tags: category-theory

Every limit starts with a diagram.  It is sometimes given by a little category $J$ and a functor from $J$ into $C$ that picks out the diagram.  For a Cartesian product, say in Set, what is this diagram?  Is it just two objects and no arrows?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, two objects with no arrows is exactly the diagram that gives you the product as a limit.